# How to draw a recursive hexagon art in scheme?

Tags: scheme, turtle-graphics

[image]
If we want to draw a recursive art in scheme like the one above, how should we approach it?

Here is a rough draft that I have (not quite work as of now) edited from sierpinski triangle in scheme.

Thanks!

```
(define (hax fn)
    (repeat 6 (lambda () (fn) (lt 60))))

(define (haxa d k)
    (hax (lambda ()
            (if (= k 1) (fd d) (haxaleg d k)))))

(define (haxaleg d k)
    (haxa (/ d 2) (- k 1))
    (penup)
    (fd (* d 1.72))
    (lt 120)
    (pendown))
```

Comment: Seeing as you can't chop a hexagon up in to a whole number of hexagons, can't see how you can come up with a simple recursive description like a sierpinkski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to want to recursively draw smaller hexagons at each second corner around a hexagon, the following method shoud work.

1. Draw a hexagon of the desired size, returning to original position and direction
2. Draw smaller hexagons at current position
3. Move two sides forward, turning after each move
4. Repeat point 2 and 3 twice more

In your dialect of scheme, this should be

```
(define (hexagon length)
    (pendown)
    (repeat 6 (lambda () 
                 (fd length)
                 (lt 60)))
    (penup))

(define (hexagons length levels)
    (hexagon length)   ;; Draw big hexagon
    (if (> levels 1)
        (repeat 3 (lambda ()
                     (hexagons (/ length 2) (- levels 1))  ;; Then smaller ones,
                     (repeat 2 (lambda ()                  ;; move to next corner
                          (fd length)
                          (lt 60)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks alot Terje! Btw did you have something different earlier? I remember in your original code your hexagon function doesnt have lambda. In my dialect my scheme its kind of difficult to conceptualize the process

Comment: @IannWu I can't remember having edited the code. The lambdas in this code just groups statements to be repeated, like the way `begin` would be used with another iteration construct. Btw: If you call `pendown` before calling `hexagons`, you can omit the call to `hexagon`.